# wp_delete_attachment doesn't delete images in wp-content/uploads/

Tags: uploads

My function lets users delete their uploaded images in the front-end. However, they're only deleted in the Media Library. That means that they're still in wp-content/uploads/.

```
public static function removePhoto($ID, $attachment) {
  if(isset(self::$data['user']['photos'][$attachment])) {
    unset(self::$data['user']['photos'][$attachment]);
    wp_delete_attachment($attachment);
    core:updateUserMeta($ID, 'photos', self::$data['user']['photos']);
  }
}
```

This is how how the images are added:

```
public static function uploadImage($file) {
  require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  $attachment=array('ID' => 0);
  if(JBSUser::$data['user']['membership']['photos']<=0) {
    JBSInterface::$messages[]=__('You have exceeded the number of photos', 'epic');
    return $file;
  }

  if(!empty($file['name'])) {
    $uploads=wp_upload_dir();
    $filetype=wp_check_filetype($file['name'], null);
    $filename=wp_unique_filename($uploads['path'], 'image-1.'.$filetype['ext']);
    $filepath=$uploads['path'].'/'.$filename;

    //validate file
    if (!in_array($filetype['ext'], array('jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'png', 'PNG'))) {
      JBSInterface::$messages[]=__('Only JPG and PNG images are allowed.', 'epic');
    } else if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {

      //upload image
      $attachment=array(
          'guid' => $uploads['url'].'/'.$filename,
          'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
          'post_title' => sanitize_title(current(explode('.', $filename))),
          'post_content' => '',
          'post_status' => 'inherit',
          'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
      );

      //add image
      $attachment['ID']=wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $attachment['guid'], 0);
      update_post_meta($attachment['ID'], '_wp_attached_file', substr($uploads['subdir'], 1).'/'.$filename);

      //add thumbnails
      $metadata=wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment['ID'], $filepath);
      wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment['ID'], $metadata);

    } else {
      JBSInterface::$messages[]=__('This image is too large for uploading.','epic');
    }
  }

  return $attachment;
}
```

Update: Setting `wp_delete_attachment`, `true` - does not work.

I'm suspicious of: `substr($uploads['subdir'], 1).'/'.$filename);`
Which seems to upload the files to subfolder. But the images are still uploaded to the wp-content/uploads/ regardless if the "organize" setting is on or off.

Should this really effect the wp_delete_attachment?

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's because you are not adding the image via wp_handle_upload. When I add it via wp_handle_upload wp_delete_attachment works. But when adding via file_put_contents or something else it does not. Did you figure this out otherwise? I tried unlink(), but you need to provide all thumbnail images then (300x300 etc..)

Comment: @trainoasis Doesnt work for me either, I am adding files through`media_handle_upload` though (after sanitization) - which basically calls `wp_handle_upload` inside

Comment: Why was this closed as off topic???? This is so on topic.. I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if your attachment gets deleted but not your files

There is a filter `wp_delete_file`, check if this filter is hooked on somewhere, if it returns `null` your file won't be deleted but the attachment will

For me it was due to the WPML plugin, they duplicate attachments and then checks that all the attachments are deleted before actually deleting the file

You can either add this action in your theme/plugin, that will delete all translations when using `$force_delete` in `wp_delete_attachment`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'delete_attachment_translations' ) ) {
    function delete_attachment_translations( $id ) {
        remove_action( 'delete_attachment', 'delete_attachment_translations' );

        $langs = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', [] );

        if ( ! empty( $langs ) ) {
            global $wp_filter;

            //We need to temporarly remove WPML's hook or they will cache the result and not delete the file
            // Sadly they used a filter on a non global class instance, so we cannot access it via regular wp hook
            $hooks = $wp_filter['wp_delete_file']->callbacks[10];
            unset( $wp_filter['wp_delete_file']->callbacks[10] );

            foreach ( $langs as $code => $info ) {
                $post_id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $id, 'attachment', false, $code );
                if ( $id == $post_id ) {
                    continue;
                }
                wp_delete_attachment( $post_id, true );
            }

            $wp_filter['wp_delete_file']->callbacks[10] = $hooks;
        }

        add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'delete_attachment_translations' );
    }

    add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'delete_attachment_translations' );
}
```

Or check this option in your WPML settings (But it applies to all posts types, not just attachments)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by: "file won't be deleted but the attachment will". Are file and attachment not referring to the same thing?

Comment: No they are not, the attachment is the database entity referencing the file, the file is the actual file on the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide [wp_delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment) a value of true for it's second argument `force_delete`. Your code needs to change to `wp_delete_attachment( $attachment, true );`

Comment: Adding the value true to wp_delete_attachment doesnt fix the issue. The uploaded file is still in wp_content/uploads

Comment: What do you think about the substr($uploads['subdir'], 1).'/'.$filename); in the upload function?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add second parameter for the function [wp_delete_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)

```
 <?php wp_delete_attachment( $attachmentid, $force_delete ); ?>
```

> $attachmentid 
>   (integer) (required) The ID of the attachment you would
>   like to delete. 
> Default: None
>
> $force_delete (bool) (optional) Whether to bypass trash and force
>   deletion (added in WordPress 2.9). 
>   Default: false

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But adding force_delete does not fix the issue.

Comment: What do you think about the substr($uploads['subdir'], 1).'/'.$filename); in the upload function?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `wp-includes/post.php` in the `wp_delete_attachment_files` there's a check to see if other attachments use the same file. This is what was happening in my case. Because I initially deleted the file manually but not the attachment, when I was uploading it again, the same name as before was used.

So when the delete function was called for the newly uploaded attachment id, the old attachment had a reference to the same file, so the DB attachment was deleted and not the file.

Make sure you manually delete all the attachments that could point to the same file from the media library.